# Command for restarting all running docker containers?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

How to restart all running docker containers? Mainly looking for a shortcut instead of doing

> docker restart containerid1 containerid2

Answer (score 308, accepted):

Just run

`docker restart $(docker ps -q)`

**Update**

For restarting **ALL** (*stopped* and *running*) containers use `docker restart $(docker ps -a -q)` as in answer lower.

Comment: I know `-a` lists containers not running, but what does `-q` stand for?

Comment: from `docker ps --help`:

`-q, --quiet           Only display numeric IDs`

You can get help for every docker command by command `docker [command] --help`

Comment: this attempts to start a container for every value in the table output of `docker ps --all`, so it will try to run `docker restart 'up for 2 weeks ago'`, `docker restart '33060/tcp'` and so on. Better to somehow limit the output of the `docker ps` command to just the name column. For example `docker restart $(docker ps --all --format "{{.Names}}")`

Comment: -1 because the updated answer restarts _**all containers**_ whereas the original question is to restart _all **running** containers_.

Comment: You are right John. I corrected my updated answer.

Comment: For me, this command gave the following error:      "docker restart" requires at least 1 argument. Adding '-a' option along with '-q' option worked.

Answer (score 112):

For me its now :

```
docker restart $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Comment: worth to mention to everyone, that it works in powershell only

Comment: Powershell only? No, it works in Bash too...

Comment: Agree, It works in bash as well.

Comment: This will restart all containers stopped and running.

Answer (score 30):

If you have `docker-compose`, all you need to do is:

```
docker-compose restart
```

And you get nice print out of the container's name along with its status of the restart (done/error)

Here is the official guide for installing: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

Comment: I have multiple projects running on a VPS and sometimes after a restart some of them have troubles starting and I'd have to move to every docker project and do that but other answers work to start ALL of them, not only one.

Answer (score 30):

To start only stopped containers:

```
docker start $(docker ps -a -q -f status=exited)
```

(On windows it works in Powershell).

Answer (score 12):

To start all the containers:

```
  docker restart $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Use sudo if you don't have permission to perform this:

```
sudo docker restart $(sudo docker ps -a -q)
```

Answer (score 4):

To restart all the online docker containers

```
docker restart $(docker ps -a -q -f status=healthy)
```

To start all the stopped containers:

```
docker start $(docker ps -a -q -f status=exited)
```

Other status options can be:

`created`, `restarting`, `running`, `removing`, `paused`, `exited`, `dead`.

Answer (score 0):

To start multiple containers with the only particular container ids `$ docker restart container-id1 container-id2 container-id3 ...`

Answer (score 0):

An other way `docker ps -q | xargs docker restart`

Answer (score -1):

start last 5 containers

```
 docker start $(docker ps -n 5 -q)
```