Bash Loop to get Docker Container names & start them if not running
On reboot some of my containers (at random) don't run as I am running on a less powerful ARM64 SBC, however, these run good enough if initiated with some delay
I used following x3 threads
1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/51611701/1162750
2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/52959534/1162750
Partial solution that works
items=$(docker ps -a -q -f status=exited)
for word in $items
do
    docker restart $word
    sleep 10
done

items=$(docker ps -a -q -f status=created)
for word in $items
do
    docker restart $word
    sleep 10
done

Above code initiates all of my containers at reboot but as seen uses x2 loops & no feedback from container. I cannot find how to use OR in status to get x1 loop
To get feedback (if container is indeed running healthy) I need to use this 3rd thread code but some suggestions will be helpful
3] https://stackoverflow.com/a/33520390/1162750

Re "I cannot find how to use OR in status": If docker itself doesn't provide an option for this (which I don't know), try items=$(docker ps -a -q -f status=exited; docker ps -a -q -f status=created).

Thanks it helped. Now how can I ask docker for a feedback about $word if it is healthy?

This is more of docker question than a bash question but I think from my webseaching you can use multiple -f options, I don't use docker so I can't test it, let me know if this kind of thing works for you, if not we can try something else.
Code:
#!/bin/bash

container_id_list=$(docker ps -a -q -f "status=exited" -f "status=created")

for container_id in $container_id_list; do

    docker restart "${container_id}"
    
    # Set result based on exit code
    [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && result="SUCCESS" || result="FAILED"
    
    echo "Restart of container ${container_id} - ${result}"
    sleep 10

done

Explaination
Updated the 'docker ps' command to capture both of your needs. Added in restart the container by ID and verify it was started with feedback from the exit code.
Note: Be mindful of your variable naming.

This worked perfectly well. However, it is not auto-initiated when referenced in/etc/rc.local My rc-local.service is running perfectly as other commands are also included in it. Those work but this script don't. I had chmod +x it

Thanks, yeah those tweaks could certianly be needed .
